# Formula for the Pontryagin duality bracket of $\left(\mathbb{R}^{+},\times\right)$

Tags: group-theory, harmonic-analysis

Consider $G=\left(\mathbb{R}^{+},\times\right)$, the group of positive real numbers with multiplication as the group operation. Let $\hat{G}$ denote the Pontryagin dual of $G$.

By the “duality bracket”, I mean the mathematical expression—which I denote by $\left\langle x,\xi\right\rangle$—with the property that, for each $\xi\in\hat{G}$, the map $x\in G\mapsto\left\langle x,\xi\right\rangle \in\partial\mathbb{D}$
  defines a character on $G$, and, for each $x\in G$, the map $\xi\in\hat{G}\mapsto\left\langle x,\xi\right\rangle \in\partial\mathbb{D}$
  defines a character on $\hat{G}$.

As an example, for $H=\left(\mathbb{R},+\right)$
 , we have that $\hat{H}=\left(\mathbb{R},+\right)$
  and that: $$\left\langle x,\xi\right\rangle =e^{2\pi ix\xi}$$

What is the corresponding formula for $\left\langle x,\xi\right\rangle $
  for $G$
  (and, in this context, what subset of $\mathbb{C}$
  is $\hat{G}$
  identified with so that the formula for $\left\langle x,\xi\right\rangle$ 
  makes sense)?

Note: I don't want an explanation, I just want the formula. I can't find a straight answer on the internet, so I thought I might as well ask.

Additional Note: If anyone knows of a handy link to a chart or list of duality brackets for commonly-used groups, it would be a great help to have such a resource on hand for future reference.

Comment: just take logs to reduce to the additive group.

Comment: That's an explanation, not a formula.

Comment: So it is${}{}$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\log:G\to H$ is an isomorphism of topological groups.  So, we can identify $\hat{G}$ with $\hat{H}=(\mathbb{R},+)$, with pairing $$\langle x,\xi \rangle= e^{2\pi i \log(x) \xi}.$$